# Why do I have problems with Ext JS 6.2.0?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6.2

I'm trying to create a simple app un Netbeans with Ext JS 6.2.0.

In the ui.js file I just creat a toolbar and a form.

```js
var toolbar = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    width   : 400,
    margin  : '5 0 0 0',
    items   : [{
        xtype: 'datefield',
        anchor: '100%',
        format: 'W-Y',
        fieldLabel: 'From',
        name: 'from_date',
        maxValue: new Date()  // limited to the current date or prior
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    title: 'User Form',
    height: 300,
    width: 585,
    defaults: {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        labelAlign: 'top',
        padding: 10
    },
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [toolbar]
});
```

Then in the index.jsp I call this file and the other files such as theme-classic-all-debug.css, theme-classic-debug.js and ext-all-debug.js.

I incorprate this with these tags:

```html
<script src="WEB-INF/ext-6.2.0/build/ext-all-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="WEB-INF/ext-6.2.0/build/classic/theme-classic/resources/theme-classic-all-debug.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

But the problem is that when I'm trying to run the application, in the console of the browser, I see these errors and the page doesn't show anything.

The errors:

---SPANISH---

```
El script de “http://localhost:8080/pruebaMCC/WEB-INF/ext-6.2.0/build/ext-all-debug.js” fue cargado a pesar de que su tipo MIME (“text/html”) no es un tipo MIME válido de JavaScript.

Ha fallado la carga del <script> con origen "http://localhost:8080/pruebaMCC/WEB-INF/ext-6.2.0/build/ext-all-debug.js".
```

---ENGLISH---

```
<script> loading with source "http: // localhost: 8080 / test MCC / WEB-INF / ext-6.2.0 / build / ext-all-debug.js" failed.
```

I don't know how can I resolve it.

Please help me.

Thanks,
Sofy

Comment: Are you take 404 status from response on request for this resource?

Comment: looks like you reference is wrong for the ext-all-debug.js file.. Check the path.. Is the WEB-INF folder really there and is it under 'test MCC' or 'pruebaMCC' ?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the problem is that there are no static resources. To access resources from the `jsp` template, it is not enough to indicate the path to the resources on your computer. Afterwards the java code will be compiled and build and your resources will be packed into a `jar` or `war` with which the server will then work. And the final path depends on the context to which deploy jar.

Try

```
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/ext-6.2.0/build/ext-all-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/ext-6.2.0/build/classic/theme-classic/resources/theme-classic-all-debug.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

It may not help. It all depends at your settings in java project.